# Azure App Service application settings not overriding application.json array setting for .NET Core 3.1 application

Tags: azure, .net-core, configuration, appsettings

We have a .NET Core 3.1 application deployed to Microsoft Azure.
In the application.json file of the application we have the following contents:

```
{
"Settings": {
    "ServicesURIs": [
      {
        "Name": "Features",
        "URL": "https://abc.azurewebsites.net",
        "Port": "443",
        "ScopeUri": "api://xxxxxx",
        "enabled": "true"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Questions",
        "URL": "https://def.azurewebsites.net",
        "Port": "443",
        "ScopeUri": "api://XXXXX",
        "enabled": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "pwa": {
    "cacheId": "v1.3",
    "strategy": "networkFirst",
    "registerWebmanifest": true,
    "routesToPreCache": "/"
  }
}
```

I wish to override the URL properties from the Application settings section in Configuration of the app service in Azure.

I am currently specifying the following application setting in the configuration blade per documentation and lots of online blogs:

```
Name= Settings:ServicesURIs:0:URL
Value= https://Somevalidurl.azurewebsites.net
```

But I find that the application is not using the value from the portal configuration, and always try to use the value in the .json file.

I have tried specifying the name as

```
Settings__ServicesURIs__0__URL
```

(where the ":" are replaced with double underscores)

I have restarted the application service after registering the setting in Azure.

I test this using Chrome in Incognito to ensure cache is not playing a role.